# How to meaningfully define hashCode and equals for a java.lang.Class<T>?

Tags: java, hash, hashmap, equals, hashcode

If one needs to use a `Class<T>` as part of a key of a `Map` what is the proper way to define the `hashCode` and `equals`?
A `Class<T>` inherits the ones from `Object` which check for reference equality and return the memory address as the hashcode but in my mind it is not clear what is the meaningful definition of `equals` and `hashCode` definition of a `Class<T>`.
Should I use `theClass.getClass().hashCode();` for example (where we have `Class<T> theClass;`)  to use the actual instance's methods?
But this does not seem to be the correct thing to do.
For example in the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) for `Class<T>`:

> Every array also belongs to a class that is reflected as a Class
>   object that is shared by all arrays with the same element type and
>   number of dimensions

So it seems in some cases the same `Class<T>` is shared among objects? So what would be the way to follow? Perhaps use `theClass.hashCode()` and `theClass.equals()` to use reference equality? Not sure at all here.

Comment: There is nothing to define, since hashcode and equals are already implemented, and I have a hard time imagining how and a even harder time imagining why you would change that implementation.

Comment: @JensSchauder:Using Eclipse to automatically generate `hashCode` and `equals` it gave a warning complaining that the `hashCode` and `equals` are not defined for `Class`.This got me concerned whether it is a valid warning and I should do something about it.

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to do, but 'Class' is a class that is part of java itself. You cannot implement anything for it. What is the full name of the source file where you try to add hashCode and equals?

Comment: @JensSchauder:Not sure what you are asking by source file.`Class<T>` is a member of a class that could be used as a key in a `Map`

Comment: No, Class<T> is a type implemented by the class java.lang.Class. There is exactly one instance for every class T. Its type is Class<T>.

Comment: How about a code example for the problem you want solved.

Comment: @JensSchauder:A custom class that serves as a `Key` in a `Map`. *One* of the members of the class is a `Class<T>`.

Comment: @Cratylus: Your question is interesting, but somehow forgot to define your goals - what is "meaningful" equals when the preexisting is not?

Comment: @maaartinus:The preexisting equals just compares references.In my case, is this something one would consider as meaningful to compare?

Comment: @Cratylus: Sometimes yes. I wrote such classes already, their instances are equal only when referring to the very same class. I see two classes as equal IFF they have the same name and the same classloader... and there are no two different instances of `Class` being equals in this sense (unless a classloader is misbehaving ). The situation is similar to enums, where `==` also suffices.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The implementation of `hashCode` and `equals` `java.lang.Class` inherits from `java.lang.Object` is meaningful and usually appropriate, as all instances of a class are guaranteed to return the *same* `Class` object from `getClass()`, i.e.

```
new Integer(2).getClass() == new Integer(3).getClass();
```

This is somewhat buried in the docs; the [javadoc of getClass()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass%28%29) writes:

> Returns:
>
> The Class object that represents the runtime class of this object.
>
> See Also:
>
> Literals, section 15.8.2 of The Java™ Language Specification.

[That section](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.2) writes:

> A class literal evaluates to the Class object for the named type (or for void) as defined by the defining class loader (§12.2) of the class of the current instance.

and [section 12.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.2) writes:

> Well-behaved class loaders maintain these properties:
>
> - Given the same name, a good class loader should always return the same class object.
> - ...
>
> A malicious class loader could violate these properties. However, it could not undermine the security of the type system, because the Java virtual machine guards against this.

And yes, if the same class definition is loaded by different class loaders, the class objects will not be equal. As the runtime treats these as independent classes (who just happen to share the same name, but need not otherwise be similar, let alone binary compatible), this is usually desired.

Comment: Side note on this: Applications like Tomcat use a hierarchical classloader and this can bite you. Tomcat gives all it's applications their own classloader stack.

Answer (score 0):

The method `String getName()` returns a **unique** String representation of the Class. You can use this String for equals/hashCode as an ordinary String if your program does not use more than one classloader.

Comment: But I don't do `Map<Class<T>,T>`.My question is when `Class<T>` is **part** of a key.Not the key itself

Comment: @Cratylus The answer is the same; you use getName() which returns a unique String representation of the Class object; you use this string in hashing/equals as if it were a String instance field.